# Error while registering

Tags: 7, users

When I register as a new user I get an error.

`An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.`

If I reenter my password fields, and press create new account then it lets me register. Ideas?

Comment: Hi. are you using Login Toboggan or any other module that alters the regular login or register process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An illegal choice typically means that the Form API received something it didn't expect when the form was processed. As Stan Ascher says, make sure you don't have modules enabled which modify the login process. You can tell if there are functions which end in _user or _form_alter in those modules.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any customizations in registration page. Or you are using a default drupal registration form.

Comment: Using the captcha module